# UIKeyboardWillHideNotification and textFieldDidEndEditing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextfield

In one of my project, when the keyboard is shown up and I press the done button, I had textFieldDidEndEditing called first and then it will trigger the target function of the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification. However in my other project it is the other way around (notification function then textFieldDidEndEditing, which is what I want). Why is this? Both are tested on the iOS simulator v. 5.1. How can I ensure that one is called before the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

to capture the Done or Return key being pressed?

Comment: I am already using that.. but prior to this the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification selector/target is function is fired off first and then the textFieldDidEndDismissal is fired. I am just confused what might be causing this to be the other way around

Comment: The UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is a notification not a method.  This is something that you would need to set your class up as a listener for and then fire off a selector when that notification is sent.  The advantage (in this case) for using the delegate method textFieldShouldReturn is that the TextField is passed into the delegate method so you would know exactly which TextField caused it to be fired.  With the notification, you would simply know that a control of ANY kind caused the keyboard to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Set UITextFieldDelegate in your .h and in your .m :

```
[self.myTextField setdelegate:self];
```

Comment: In your `.h`, set the delegate. In your `.m`, put that line in `viewDidLoad`.